Prove $\mathrm{argmax}_{i} \frac{x_i}{L+y_i}$ is same as of $\mathrm{argmax}_{i} \frac{x_i^2}{L+y_i^2}$
Suppose $x$ is a set such that $x = [x_1, x_2, \dots]$ and $x_i \geq 0$, also let $y = [y_1, y_2, \dots]$ and $y_i>0$. How can I prove that
$$\mathrm{argmax}_{i \in \{1,2,\dots\}} \frac{x_i}{L+y_i} = \mathrm{argmax}_{i \in \{1,2,\dots\}} \frac{x_i^2}{L+y_i^2}.$$
I have no idea where to begin and even how to approach such a problem. Anybody please help in giving hints or providing a solution.
Thanks
Edit :
From the answer of @NN2, its clear that $\mathrm{argmax}_{i \in \{1,2,\dots\}} \frac{x_i}{L+y_i}$ is not always equal to $\mathrm{argmax}_{i \in \{1,2,\dots\}} \frac{x_i^2}{L+y_i^2}.$. Is there any way to find the conditions in which they are equal?

Do we have $L>0$?

@GBmath: Yes $L > 0$

Here is a counter example:
$$\begin{align}
&L =\frac{4}{5}\\
&(x_1,x_2)=\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}  \right)\\
&(y_1,y_2)=\left(\frac{1}{3},1 \right)\\
\end{align}$$
Then the first $\text{argmax}$ is $i=1$ while the second is $\text{argmax}$ $i =2$:
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{x_1}{L+y_1}=\frac{5}{17}\color{red}>\frac{5}{18}=\frac{x_2}{L+y_2}\\
&\frac{x_1^2}{L+y_1^2}=\frac{5}{41}\color{red}<\frac{5}{36}=\frac{x_2^2}{L+y_2^2}\\
\end{align}$$

I think you are making a mistake in your own example, in both cases $i=2$ is $\mathrm{argmax}$ in both cases. In the first case $\frac{x}{L+y} = \left[\frac{10}{39} \frac{5}{18}\right]$ for $i = [1,2]$. And in the second case $\frac{x^2}{L+y^2} = \left[\frac{20}{189} \frac{5}{36}\right]$ for $i = [1,2]$. Thus in both cases $i=2$ is the maximum value. I think you made some calculation error, I have thoroughly checked this thing, I just need the mathematical ways to prove it

@coolname11 Ah, I made a typo by writing $y_2 = 1/2$. $y_2$ should be equal to $\color{red}{1/3}$. I just edited this typo. All the calculation is unchanged. Check again, the counter example is still correct.

Is there a way to find in what conditions, they will be equal?

@coolname11 You must have
$$\frac{x_i}{L+y_i}\le \frac{x_j}{L+y_j}\iff \frac{x_i^2}{L+y_i^2}\le \frac{x_j^2}{L+y_j^2}\hspace{1cm} \forall i,j \tag{}$$
I don't think there exists any simple conditions to achieve $()$.
